# JavaFx 8 MouseEvents firing inconsistently

Tags: java, mouseevent, javafx-8

**EDIT: The problems seem to emerge from the use of a SplitPane. I've removed that, but now I'm encountering MouseTransparent issues, cf comments**

I'm encountering a problem on a StackPane, where a Controller class is supposed to manage node translations via mouse dragging:

For some reason, the .setOnMouseEntered event correctly fires whenever the mouse enters the StackPane. However, setOnMousePressed (when clicking on a node in the StackPane) doesn't fire at all, except on a label in the center of the StackPane. When I remove the label, nothing fires. The StackPane itself is comprised of a SplitPane, which is comprised of several other nodes.

Some of those nodes (the ones supposed to be dragged around) also have some setOnMousePressed, etc event management, which gets fired correctly !

To understand the context a bit more: I am working on a Naval Battle game implementation. I am currently trying to manage the boat placement via a controller class (so that I can verify that a boat doesn't get placed out of bounds or on another boat). The controller class (BoatMoveManager), when instancied, creates all these mouseEvent handlers on the highest StackPane (GameBoard extends StackPane).

```
public class BoatMoveManager {
    GameBoard gB;

    public BoatMoveManager(GameBoard g){
        gB = g;

        //the following mouseEventHandler fires correctly whenever the mouse enters the GameBoard (StackPane)
        gB.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            System.out.println("GameBoard OnMouseEntered");

        //the following mouseEventHandler doesn't fire, except on a label in the middle of the GameBoard
        gB.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            System.out.println("GameBoard OnMousePressed");
        });
```

I don't understand why the event fires with the label, and not with the rest of the nodes in the GameBoard... (It might be the fact that the label is directly "inside" the GameBoard, while other nodes are in the top part of a horizontal splitter ?)

For example, here is the constructor for the GameBoard:

```
public class GameBoard extends StackPane {
    private SplitPane splitter;
    private TilePane gameZone;
    private TabZone tabs;
    private Grid playerGrid, opponentGrid, playerHarbor, opponentHarbor;
    private FlowPane playerGrids, opponentGrids, playerZone, opponentZone;
    private Score playerScore, opponentScore;
    private Label popup;

    private static HBox playerHBox, opponentHBox;
    private static VBox playerVBox, opponentVBox;

    private static BoatMoveManager bMM;

    private List<Boat> playerBoatsList = new ArrayList<Boat>(), opponentBoatsList = new ArrayList<Boat>() ;

    public GameBoard(){
        super();

        playerGrid = new Grid('G','H');
        opponentGrid = new Grid('G','H');
        playerHarbor = new Grid('H','H');
        opponentHarbor = new Grid('H','H');

        bMM = new BoatMoveManager(this);

        for(int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; ++i){
            playerBoatsList.add(new Boat(i, playerGrid, playerHarbor));
            opponentBoatsList.add(new Boat(i, opponentHarbor, opponentGrid));
        }

        playerGrid.drawBoat(playerBoatsList.get(0), 3, 4);
        playerGrid.drawBoat(playerBoatsList.get(1), 3, 5);
        playerGrid.drawBoat(playerBoatsList.get(2), 3, 6);
        playerGrid.drawBoat(playerBoatsList.get(3), 3, 7);

        playerScore = new Score();
        opponentScore = new Score();

        gameZone = new TilePane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        gameZone.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgray");

        playerHBox = new HBox();
        playerHBox.getChildren().addAll(playerHarbor, playerGrid);

        playerHBox.setSpacing(Grid.getUnit());

        playerVBox = new VBox();
        playerVBox.getChildren().addAll(playerScore,playerHBox);
        playerVBox.maxWidthProperty().bind(gameZone.widthProperty().divide(2));
        playerScore.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        opponentHBox = new HBox();
        opponentHBox.getChildren().addAll(opponentGrid, opponentHarbor);
        opponentHBox.setSpacing(Grid.getUnit());

        opponentVBox = new VBox();
        opponentVBox.getChildren().addAll(opponentScore,opponentHBox);
        opponentScore.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        gameZone.getChildren().addAll(playerVBox, opponentVBox);
        gameZone.setHgap(Grid.getUnit()*3);
        gameZone.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        gameZone.setSnapToPixel(false);
        tabs = new TabZone();

        splitter = new SplitPane();
        splitter.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        splitter.setDividerPositions(0.75f,0.25f);
        splitter.getItems().addAll(gameZone,tabs);

        splitter.setOnDragEntered(event ->{
            BoatMoveManager.setTarget(splitter);
        });

        popup = new Label("uninitialized");

        this.getChildren().addAll(splitter,popup);

        this.setOnDragEntered(event -> {
            BoatMoveManager.setTarget(this);
        });
    }
```

The label I'm talking about is "popup", which is added at the very end of the constructor along with "splitter" in

```
this.getChildren().addAll(splitter,popup);
```

but take in account the fact that even when I don't add it, events like MousePressed don't fire through GameBoard...

Here's a layout of the GameBoard to clear things up (grids and boats layout is self explanatory): 
[image: GameBoard layout]
(Open this image in a new tab to view it in full size)
I hope this isn't too cluttered to get a sense of what I'm trying to do.. And why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I have done some research, and the problem seems to emerge from the SplitPane. When I add the gameZone directly to the GameBoard StackPane, events fire correctly ! Wierd

Comment: Allright, I am at a point now where I can get MouseEvents to fire correctly. HOWEVER, when I start a press-drag-release gesture, even though I set the source node to be mouseTransparent(true), I can't get further dragEntered events  on other nodes to fire at all... I followed the Official JavaFx-8 Doc which said to set mouseTransparent(true) on mouse press and set mouseTransparent(false) on mouse released. The DragDetected event fires correctly, but nothing else. I'm loosing my shit here :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure at this point. I'd pretty much have to test the code on my computer to know for sure but try

```
this.setMouseTransparency(true);
```

This will make it to where the stackpane itself can't be clicked on. Also for future reference you can drop the "this" at the beginning of your calls for GameBoard. It's perfectly legal to call getChildren().add(node) if your class extends StackPane.

Comment: `this.setMouseTransparent(true)` makes all of the nodes inside the GameBoard StackPane transparent to mouse as well...

Comment: Have you posted the entire code? I mean can I run this on my computer?

Comment: It won't work if you try, but I found out that events fire again when I remove the SplitPane from the equation. Wierd

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same problem (again) ..

I believe a StackPane is your problem. They do not like to pass event aparently..
In my case, setting :
*stackPane*.setPickOnBounds(false);

was my fix.

I hope this resolves the Issue for you.. perhaps a bug?

Comment: Then my next suggestion is to look at the order of children, a container node may have its size scaled to fit the scene (like in fxml) unless specifically stated which may be blocking mouse events passing to a node like a button behind it.

and after seeing above comments, I bet that it is the root container in the SplitPane, have you tried setting your container as the root?

Comment: root.setPrefSize(*Pane.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, *Pane.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you define as 'root' ? The splitPane has two items; gameZone (which contains a lot of other sub-Nodes) and tabs (which is just an extended TabPane class). I've tried replacing the SplitPane with a VBox, which then made the MouseEvents fire correctly. But now I'm sitting with my display cut perfectly in two halves of the screen, instead of a draggable splitter... :@

Comment: I was using "root" generically, referring to Container nodes.
example, if you set a Stackpane as the Scene's rootNode, unless you specifically set it's size it will scale to fit the whole scene

Comment: The thing is, our teachers specifically asked us to not use FXML... But anyway, I am indeed using a StackPane as root for the scene. The SplitPane is contained in it, a few layers under.

Comment: I have Figured it out!!!

StackPane's are the culprit..

try this: on your main stackpane container :: *.setPickOnBounds(false); 
in my project I just had the same happen and this was my fix.. 
I'll edit my op for ease with other users.